# Generate map file only in Release using Delphi?

Tags: delphi, map-files

I'm using JCL to generate jdbg file and insert it into the exe. 
In the .dpr file I have the following lines:

```
// JCL_DEBUG_EXPERT_GENERATEJDBG ON
// JCL_DEBUG_EXPERT_INSERTJDBG ON
// JCL_DEBUG_EXPERT_DELETEMAPFILE ON
```

Project Options -> linking, settings for map file are the following: 
**Debug configuration - All platforms:**
Map file, 32-bit Windows, 64-bit Windows platform only: *Off* 
**Release configuration - All platforms:**
Map file, 32-bit Windows, 64-bit Windows platform only: *Detailed*

When I compile in debug mode, .map file is generated, and the linking option in Debug Configuration becomes "Detailed".

Why is this happening? How can I fix this? I want map file to be generated only when i compile the project in release mode.

Comment: Try to experiment on the empty new project. If behavior repeted this is bug. Otherwise... 1) Check option for specific configuration(namely for Debug Win32 or Debug Win64) 2) Try check dproj file

Comment: It does the same also on a new project